# Is there a way to show all Sylius products in one view?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I know one can use show products by taxonomy but what if I would like to show all products in one view no matter the category the product is in?

Is it possible in Sylius or do I have to write my own controller that will use query builder to output all of them? And if yes, then how? Iterate over all taxons and throw barrage of queries at ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Sylius bundles. Firstly, create a new route, for example in `config/routes/sylius_shop.yaml`:

```
sylius_shop_product_all:
    path: /all
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.product:indexAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusShop/Product/index.html.twig"
            grid: sylius_shop_custom_filter
```

Then define a `sylius_shop_custom_filter` grid. If you don't know how to do it, check [documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.5/customization/grid.html).
There disable the `taxon` argument to repository method like this:

```
        sylius_shop_custom_filter:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: "%sylius.model.product.class%"
                    repository:
                        method: findAllByChannel
                        arguments:
                            channel: "expr:service('sylius.context.channel').getChannel()"
                            # taxon: "expr:notFoundOnNull(service('sylius.repository.taxon').findAll)"
                            locale: "expr:service('sylius.context.locale').getLocaleCode()"
                            sorting: "expr:service('request_stack').getCurrentRequest().get('sorting', [])"
```

Then extend ProductRepository as in [documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.5/customization/repository.html), copy `createShopListQueryBuilder` method from parent repository and name it `findAllByChannel`. There disable not used `$taxon` argument from querybuilder.

Comment: Great, thank you. It seems a lot of hassle to do something I thought would be in sylius out of the box.